# Asynchronous push messaging to browser without websockets

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, asynchronous, websocket

We have a browser-based application that currently uses websockets to receive messages asynchronously from our server. For websockets we are using python autobahn on the server side and javascript/jQuery on the client side. We also had auto failover to long polling if the websocket connection failed for whatever reason. All this made sense when our app received frequent messages from the server.

However, our infrastructure is changing a bit, and now we expect to receive messages very infrequently. The only catch is that we'd like to receive those messages with as little delay as possible (which means long polling is only marginally desirable). If we open a websocket and keep that open but nothing goes over it most of the time, then we are wasting resources and are forced to send keep-alive messages just to keep the websocket open.

So, is there some other decent asynchronous messaging technology that we can consider other than websockets? Is there some technology that can be used on the client side (hopefully in Javascript or jQuery) that can listen for occasional messages from the server and respond accordingly, something that doesn't use websockets?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid no.

There is [Server Sent Events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/), but it is not implemented in [retarded browsers](http://caniuse.com/eventsource). So your only safe option is long polling.

WebSocket protocol defines [ping and pong frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2). Ping frames can be as short as 2 bytes, and the pong would be 6 bytes (2 for header, 4 for key), so it is not so much overhead. If your server sends a ping frame, Chrome will respond with a pong frame. I wrote a WebSocket server, and that is how I keep the connection alive and detect half open connections.

Cheers.

Comment: Link to "retarded browsers" now shows no support only in IE and Opera Mini.